# Google Analytics and Google Data Studio show a different 'Users' metric

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

There's a discrepancy between Google Analytics and Google Data Studio data. The metric "Users" displayed in Google Analytics is different from the one shown in Google Data Studio when I query the number of users per month.

The query is the same on both platforms. See attached picture for more details (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkgLg.jpg).

No filters are used.
No segments are used.
No sampling applies (indeed, I'm querying the month of August only).

Is Google Data Studio just broken or am I missing something stupid?

Thanks in advance